# Returning np.array or np.matrix objects in a theano function

Tags: python-2.7, numeric

I have to do something like this.

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

x, y = T.dscalars('x', 'y')
z = np.matrix([[x*y, x-y], [x/y, x**2/(2*y)]])

f = th.function([x, y], z)   # causes error

# next comes calculations like f(2, 1)*f(3, 2)*some_matrix
```

I know the last line is not a valid code as th.function doesn't support returning these objects. Is there an efficient way to do this without returning all elements of matrix and casting it as an np.matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that z needs to be a list of theano variables not a numpy matrix.

You can achieve the same result using:

```
z1,z2,z3,z4 = x*y,x-y,x/y,x**2/(2*y)
f = th.function([x, y], [z1,z2,z3,z4])

def createz(z1,z2,z3,z4) :
    return np.matrix([[z1,z2],[z3,z4]])

print(createz(*f(1,2)))
```